# Android: integrating Google signin under android M -> use_credentials?

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

The official google doc for integration still says to have the permission use_credentials:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

where it says: "

To retrieve OAuth 2.0 tokens or invalidate tokens to disconnect a user's Google account from an app.

"

however, this permission (use_credentials) has been retired under android M, so the recommendation to include it seems out of place. Is there a more recent integration guide/doc that takes into account the change with the permission under M?